# How to build Pytorch Mobile sample HelloWorld app?

Tags: android, gradle, pytorch

https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/

I am trying to build a Pytorch demo HelloWorld app for Android. My machine is MacOS Mojave where I installed Python3 and Torchvision via conda. I am new to Pytorch, Pytorch mobile and gradlew etc.. In the past I used CMake and Make for C/C++ builds. I tried the following steps from the pytorch website but installDebug is not found. gradlew tasks definitely doesn't have any installDebug tasks.

Is the documentation old or am I missing a step or two below? I do have Android SDK and NDK installed as far as I can tell.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app.git
$ cd android-demo-app
$ cd HelloWorldApp
$ python trace_model.py
$ ./gradlew installDebug
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in root project 'HelloWorldApp'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
$ ./gradlew tasks
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably Android SDK wasn't found, try:
`export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk`

Default location on linux: ~/Android/SDK/